# What is the best calling convention in Fortran for mixed language programming with C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, fortran, calling-convention, fortran-iso-c-binding

Since several years, I've the opportunity to maintain and develop Fortran code. I started with the Compaq compiler `df` and switched to the Intel one `ifort`, some years ago. Therefore my Fortran projects still use the calling convention `cvf`.
Now, I want to start with mixed language programming with the focus on Fortran, C and C++. I know that there are many discussions and hints available in the web, especially supported and answered by Steve Lionel aka Dr. Fortran, i.e.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/298583

or the Intel help itself

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678228.

The calling convention has to be defined for the Intel Fortran Compiler only for Windows by the language option `/iface:<keyword>`where  `<keyword>` has the values `default`, `cref`, `cvf`, `[no]mixed_str_len-arg`, `stdcall` and `stdref`. The differences between `cvf`(Compaq Visual Fortran) and `default` e.g. are `C` vs. `STDCALL` for calling mechanism, character length passing after argument vs. at the end of argument list and number of bytes to be removed from stack via `@n` suffix for `cvf`.

Unfortunately I haven't found a clear statement on which calling convention is the best or shall be preferred for mixed language programming between Fortran, C and C++, yet.
So, which calling convention is the best and what are the reasons for your suggestion?

Last, but not least, I want to exchange characters/strings between Fortran, C and C++, especially as I want to use C++ libraries for Ini file handling, e.g.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5401/CIni.

The exchanged strings shall not contain `char(0)` to label the string ending.
I want to use CIni as dynamic library for my Fortran software.
On the other hand I also want to provide Fortran code as dynamic library to C++.

Target OS: Windows
Architecture: IA-32
IDE: Visual Studio
Fortran compiler: Intel Fortran 14.0.0063.2010 and higher
C and C++ compiler: Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 and higher

Are there any objectif arguments to use a certain calling convention for my purpose?

Comment: If there is no clear common opinion on a question like this, then usually it is heavily opinion based or, slightly more "scientific" and also more on-topic here, the answer is depending on the circumstances of each situation. So, in order to avoid the close votes for "opinion based", please provide more details on the context, to allow balancing the advantages and disadvantages. (For background, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic )

Comment: Welcome. This site is not really for recommendations and opinion-based questions, they are off-topic. Please tell us in which sense they should be *"best"*. Preferably some objective criterion.

Comment: To avoid downvotes by people who react negatively to any hint that somebody is considering C/C++ as one language, I recommend to stress a little that you are talking about a mix of the three languages C, FORTRAN and C++.

Comment: BTW it is Fortran, not FORTRAN and has been form more than 25 years.

Comment: And, actually, did you read and search the [tag:fortran-iso-c-binding] tag? This clearly **the best** way (because standard) for people doing modern Fortran. For people who know only some old FORTRAN I don't know.

Comment: Yes I did. Unfortunately I haven't found clear technical arguments (pros) to opt for a certain calling convention. But I need these arguments to check if it's worth to spend the effort to change all my Fortran projects from `cvf` to `default`.

Comment: I still reslly don't get what are the options you have in mind. Conventions for which kind of arguments? In which OS? Which conventions exactly? How do they differ? Do you care about 32bit stuff like stdcall? What exactly is the cvf calling covention? How do you use it? What is the default? How does it differ? Note these are likely **specific to your compiler**.

Comment: Hopefully my question is precise enough now to get an answer. What are the advantages of each Intel Fortran calling convention? What are the disadvantages and which one is suitable for my purpose?

Comment: I don't think you add anything useful in your last edit. I had several questions in my last comment andyou didn't answer any of them. I donjt think an answer is possible and that's why non-one ansered your question while many other questions received their answers quickly. Especially: **what is cvf, what is default and how do they differ**?

Comment: @VladimirF: The description of `cvf` and `default` is availabe [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/678228). But I'll add an explanation in my question, too.

Comment: And what do you want to hear in your answer? They are just two equally possible options how to pass stuff. Do you really still use 32 bit? Then your main worries should be how to move to 64 bit and not this...  I don't see how any non-opinion based answer can be made. There can be some small arguments made but no-one can tell you whether you should re-write your C stuff or not, that must be your decision.

Comment: @VladimirF: Probably you're right and it's really arbitrary which calling convention to use. Unfortunately this question arise within my software team from time to time w/o a clear decision statement. Therefore I hope to receive technical advantages, e.g. regarding implementation complexity, function over-head, runtime speed, portability, .... I don't look for opion based answers, but for experience based ones.

Comment: Portability is clear, the default ones are more modern and likely conform closer to other compilers, but you have to check that with each other compiler separately. The `cvf` option is more or less to support legacy C-Fortran combinations. But do not expect any difference in runtime speed whatsoever.

Comment: As you have a choice, you should avoid legacy methods even if you intend to use 32 bit mode.  Iso c interoperability has been the standard over a decade now, and Microsoft obsoleted stdcall before that.  You can't expect a difference in performance unless you prevent otherwise feasible interprocedural optimization.

Comment: Based on your experiences and hints, I think that it's worth to change from `cvf` to `default`.